# how to enable the --stacktrace or --info or --debug or --scan option in gradle build in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting a build error in Android Studio as below, how to enable the --stacktrace or --info or --debug or --scan option in gradle build ?

```
9:14:33 PM: Executing task 'build'...

Executing tasks: [build] in project C:\Users\rbeat\AndroidStudioProjects\NewMVVM\app

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
> couldn't make a guess for com.example.newmvvm.ListViewModel.listViewModel

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
11 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 10 up-to-date
9:14:34 PM: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute the gradle build from the command line

```
gradle build --stacktrace
```

Comment: C:\Users\rbeat\AndroidStudioProjects\NewMVVM>gradlew build --stacktrace

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Comment: You need to set the JAVA_HOME variable in your systems environment variable and then point to the "bin" folder in your path settings so that your console can find it.

Comment: I installed Android Studio. I hope JAVA also got installed based on it.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin this is the path

Comment: It should be there. Go into the folder where Android Studio is installed, there should be a folder called "jdk". The JAVA_HOME folder should be the folder that is one level above the "bin" folder. Then set the full path the bin folder in the PATH environment variable

Comment: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre and PATH=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205406/discussion-between-angus-and-allkenang).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably people uses a Logger so a user could increase verbosity with --info or 
--debug.

--stacktrace and --full-stacktrace really controls what kind of output Gradle prints at the end of the build.

so you can use

```
1. gradle build --stacktrace
2. gradle build --full-stacktrace
```